# How initialize x-editable after DOM has changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, x-editable

I think this kind of noob question, but anyway
I had x-editable plugin that initilized in my document

```
 $(function(){
   $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
   $('.editable').editable();
 });
```

after I click on tab and some part of my page is refreshed via partials, the x-editable became not avaliable on this new elements.

I try to make this trick:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.editable', function(){
   $('.editable').editable();
 });
```

this works but now I must click two times to call x-editable on .editable element, first time to initialize x-editable and second time to call x-editable popover.

What's the best practice in this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can mark new .editable somehow -for sample - `.unprocessed` and wait after click when `.editable.unprocessed` appears (`setTimeout()` - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) and then do it editable
2. You can return your data from server with .js.erb view and after refreshing page parts add

   ```
   $('.editable').editable();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's been a while since this question was posted I would like to add something to your solution. You can trigger the show method just after the element has been initilized as 'editable'.

```
    $(document).on('click','.editable',function(){
        $('.officer-editable').editable('show');
    })
```